# Django ORM Select Column From Two Model or More

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-orm

I want select column with django orm from two model or more.

```
SELECT nim, k.kode, s.nama, sks, nilai, th_ajaran FROM mahasiswa_khs k, mata_kuliah_si s WHERE k.kode = s.kode AND nim = %s
```

This is my code

```
khs = Khs.objects.filter(nim=nim).values_list('kode').union(SI.objects.all().values_list('kode'))
```

But, went I call in template it's didn't show

It's my template :

```
{% for khs in khs %}
                        <tr>
                          <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
                          <td>{{khs.kode}}</td>
                          <td>{{khs.nama}}</td>
                          <td>{{khs.sks}}</td>
                          <td class="vertical-align-mid">{{khs.nilai}}</td>
                          <th>{{khs.th_ajaran}}</th>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
```

And the view :

```
khs = Khs.objects.filter(nim=nim).union(SI.objects.all().values_list('kode'))
context ={
        'khs' : khs,
    }
    return render(request, 'mahasiswa/mahasiswa.html',context)
```

Comment: What's the reason for using `.values_list('kode')`?

Comment: to union that model, I not i got an error  'The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns')

Comment: Gotcha. Please include the template and the view in your question.

Comment: Yes, there is my template and view

Answer (score 0):

When you use `.values_list` or `.values` you're telling the ORM to only select those columns. As per the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

> This is similar to values() except that instead of returning
> dictionaries, it returns tuples when iterated over. Each tuple
> contains the value from the respective field or expression passed into
> the values_list() call — so the first item is the first field, etc.
> For example:
>
> ````
> from django.db.models.functions import Lower
> Entry.objects.values_list('id', Lower('headline')) <QuerySet [(1, 'first entry'), ...]>```
> ````

Since you're using `values_list`, this means you're pulling out a dataset that looks like: `[('kode_value_1',), ('kode_value_2', ), ...]`. In your template you'd use:

```
{% for values in khs %}
    {{ values.0 }}
{% endfor %}
```

In order to pull additional fields such as `nama`, you'd need to adjust your queryset:

khs = (
Khs.objects.filter(nim=nim)
.values_list('kode', 'nama')
.union(SI.objects.all().values_list('kode', 'nama'))
)

Then in your template you'd have:

```
{% for values in khs %}
    kode: {{ values.0 }}
    nama: {{ values.1}}
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to use the field names, then you should use `values()` instead of `values_list()` so that your template tag would be `{{ values.kode }}`

In the case that `SI` does not have the `nama` field, you can make an annotation that sets out a dummy value so the union can occur.

```
from django.db.models import Value, CharField
khs = (
    Khs.objects.filter(nim=nim)
    .values_list('kode', 'nama')
    .union(
        SI.objects
        .annotate(nama=Value(None, output_field=CharField()))
        .values_list('kode', 'nama')
    )
)
```

I took a guess that `nama` is a CharField. You may need to change that as your data model requires. The annotation approach could also work to avoid the use of `.values_list` altogether if you'd like.